# Is there a middle ground between `zip` and `zip_longest`

Tags: python

Say I have these three lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
c = [10, 11, 12]
```

Is there a builtin function such that:

```
somezip(a, b) == [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
somezip(a, c) == [(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, None)]
```

Behaving somewhere between `zip` and `zip_longest`?

Comment: In other words, a zip that always takes the length of the first argument?

Comment: @jpm: Correct. I guess that would be a better way to explain it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there isn't, but you can easily combine the functionality of [takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to achieve what you want

```
from itertools import takewhile, izip_longest
from operator import itemgetter
somezip = lambda *p: list(takewhile(itemgetter(0),izip_longest(*p)))
```

(In case the first-iterator may have items which evaluates to False, you can replace the itemgetter with a lambda expression - refer  @ovgolovin's comment)

```
somezip = lambda *p: list(takewhile(lambda e: not e[0] is None,izip_longest(*p)))
```

Examples

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile, izip_longest
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> c = [10, 11, 12]
>>> somezip(a,b)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
>>> somezip(a,c)
[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, None)]
>>> somezip(b,c)
[(5, 10), (6, 11), (7, 12), (8, None), (9, None)]
```

Comment: What if the first iterator has elements evaluating to `False`?

Comment: What if the first iterator has `None` elements? :)

Comment: It seems to me to be safe, this solution will require to create temporary unique element for padding. Because if we use `None`, first list can also contain `None`, and we can't differentiate between `None` returned by `izip_longes` and the `None`, precontained in the iterator.

Comment: One minor loss of generality is that the fillvalue has to be `None`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools as it

somezip = lambda *x: it.islice(it.izip_longest(*x), len(x[0]))



>>> list(somezip(a,b))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]

>>> list(somezip(a,c))
[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, None)]
```

Comment: Doesn't that *first* call `zip_longest` and *then* cut the result? What if one of `x` is an infinite iterator?

Comment: @JoachimSauer - no. `list(it.islice(it.count(), 10))` returns a short list.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that, neat!

Comment: That’s because `islice` generates the values on the fly from the argument which in this case (`izip_longest`) is a generator too.

Comment: If the first iterator is not a list, `len` will take extra pass to determine the length. Furthermore it will consume the iterator. (In the question the OP states that the input are lists. I just comment to clarify this point for others who may find this question relevant to their tasks).

Comment: @ovgolovin: I don't understand.  If `x[0]` is a generator, say, rather than taking an extra pass to determine the length, won't you get `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`?

Comment: @DSM You are right. I wrongly thought that `len` would consume the iterator to return its length. Now I tested and got the same exception that you cited.

Answer (score 3):

Your output seems to be restricted by the output of the first iterator `it1`. So we could use `it1` as is, and pad `it2` with infinite `None`-yielding iterator, and `zip` them.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat,izip,chain
>>> somezip = lambda it1,it2: izip(it1,chain(it2,repeat(None)))

>>> list(somezip(a,b))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
>>> list(somezip(a,c))
[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, None)]
```

[`repeat(None)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) creates iterator yielding `None` infinitely.

[`chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) glues `it2` and `repeat(None)`.

`izip` will stop yielding as soon as `it1` is exhausted.

The other solutions have some flaws (I've left remarks in the comments). They may work well, but with some input they may fail unexpectedly.

---

As **glglgl** suggested in the comments, this function would rather accept variable number of iterators in parameters.

So I updated the code to work this:

```
from itertools import repeat,izip,chain,imap
somezip = lambda it1,*its: izip(it1,*imap(chain,its,repeat(repeat(None))))
```

Test:

```
>>> print(list(somezip(a,b)))
    print(list(somezip(a,c)))
    print(list(somezip(b,a,c)))

[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
[(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, None)]
[(5, 1, 10), (6, 2, 11), (7, 3, 12), (8, 4, None), (9, None, None)]
```

I had to use `imap` here though there were no need to do so (as parameter are later unpacked, so plain `map` would do). The reason was that `map` [don't accept iterators of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348263/map-on-iterators-of-different-length), while `imap` stop while the smallest iterator is consumed.

So, `imap` applies `chain` to all the iterators except for the first one and `chain`s each of them with `repeat(None)`. To serve every iterator of `its` I used another `repeat` above `repeat(None)` (note, it may be very dangerous in the other projects, as all the objects which the outer `repeat` produces are the same object `repeat(None)`, so in the end they all the `chain`ed iterators share it). Then I unpacked `imap` object to produce the parameters to `izip`, which returns the values until `it1` is consumed (as `chain`ed `its` are now produce infinite sequence of values each).

Note that all the operations work in pure C, so there is no interpreter overhead involved.

To clarify how it works, I'm adding this elaboration:

```
def somezip(it1,*its): #from 0 to infinite iterators its
    # it1 -> a1,a2,a3,...,an
    # its -> (b1,b2,b3,...,bn),(c1,c2,c3,...,cn),...
    infinite_None = repeat(None) # None,None,None,...
    infinite_Nones = repeat(infinite_None) # infinite_None,infinite_None,... (share the same infinite_None)
    chained = imap(chain,its,infinite_Nones) # [(b1,b2,b3,...,bn,None,None,...),(c1,c2,c3,...,cn,None,None,...),...]
    return izip(it1,*chained)
```

And one-liner for it is just:

```
somezip = lambda it1,*its: izip(it1,*imap(chain,its,repeat(repeat(None))))
```

Comment: +1. One of the best, because it doesn't need to call `len(it1)`. But there must as well be a way to support an arbitrary number of iterables...

Comment: @glglgl Thanks! I thought there are only 2 iterators. I'll add the code for arbitrary number of iterators.

Comment: In the question, there are only 2. But if we can make it generic, it would be a benefit IMO, as `zip()` and `izip()` and `izip_longest()` all accept more than 2...

Comment: @glglgl I have added the variadic version!

Answer (score 0):

define your own function:

```
In [64]: def myzip(*args):
    lenn=len(args[0])
    return list(izip_longest(*[islice(x,lenn) for x in args],fillvalue=None))
   ....: 

In [30]: myzip(a,b)
Out[30]: [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]

In [31]: myzip(b,c)
Out[31]: [(5, 10), (6, 11), (7, 12), (8, None), (9, None)]

In [32]: myzip(a,c)
Out[32]: [(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is longer than the others, but relatively easy to understand, if that matters. ;-)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
c = [10, 11, 12]
def g(n): return xrange(n)  # simple generator

def my_iter(iterable, fillvalue=None):
    for i in iterable: yield i
    while True: yield fillvalue

def somezip(*iterables, **kwds):
    fillvalue = kwds.get('fillvalue')
    iters = [my_iter(i, fillvalue) for i in iterables]
    return [tuple(next(it) for it in iters) for i in iterables[0]]

print 'somezip(a, b):', somezip(a, b)
print 'somezip(a, c):', somezip(a, c)
print 'somezip(a, g(2)):', somezip(a, g(2))
print 'somezip(g(2), a):', somezip(g(2),a)
print 'somezip(a, b, c):', somezip(a, b, c)
print 'somezip(a, b, c, g(2)):', somezip(a, b, c, g(2))
print 'somezip(g(2), a, b, c):', somezip(g(2), a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
somezip(a, b): [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
somezip(a, c): [(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, None)]
somezip(a, g(2)): [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, None), (4, None)]
somezip(g(2), a): [(1, 1)]
somezip(a, b, c): [(1, 5, 10), (2, 6, 11), (3, 7, 12), (4, 8, None)]
somezip(a, b, c, g(2)): [(1, 5, 10, 0), (2, 6, 11, 1), (3, 7, 12, None), (4, 8, None, None)]
somezip(g(2), a, b, c): [(1, 1, 5, 10)]
```