# Map on iterators of different length

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13341670/862380) and faced the following problem:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> map(add,[1,2,3],[1,2])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    map(add,[1,2,3],[1,2])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I wanted `map` to stop as soon as the smallest iterator provided in the parameters is consumed.

I found the solution:

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> list(imap(add,[1,2,3],[1,2]))
[2, 4]
```

But, why is that? Shouldn't their behavior be consistent?

Is it the best way I workaround the problem?

Comment: It isn't map that is failing, it is the `add()` function. `add()` requires that you can add the two types, you cannot add a `NoneType` to an `int`. You could define your own function that can handle `None` and map would work just fine with lists of different length.

Comment: @Matt I want it to stop as soon as the *smallest* iterators is consumed.

Comment: That's acceptable, you can want that. But I was referring to the place in your question where you said `map fails when the lists of arguments are of different lengths`, which is not true. `map()` works just fine with lists of different length, the error was caused by the `add()` function.

Comment: @Matt I also provided the link to the real problem I faced (from which you can see what I was discontent about). Also, I asked several questions, one of which asks if the behavior of `map` and `imap` should be consistent. I tried to whip up a short example of failure, and the first thing which came to mind was to use `add`. I couldn't foresee, that you will attribute misbehavior to `add` non accepting `None`. So, I updated the question and clearly stated that I wanted `map` to stop as soon as the smallest iterator is consumed.

Comment: Yes, I know what you want to do. I'm not answering your question, there is already a good answer. I'm just pointing out a place where the wording in your question isn't exactly right. In your example there is an exception. That exception is raised by the `add()` function. I interpreted your 'map fails when...' to be in reference to that exception, as that is the only thing I saw that was 'failing'. My comment was about you incorrectly attributing that exception to `map()` when it was actually raised by `add()`. `map()` isn't 'failing', it is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @Matt OK! Now I hope to have edited this lack of clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described on the [`itertools.imap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) description:

> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from each of the iterables. If function is set to None, then imap() returns the arguments as a tuple. **Like map() but stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted instead of filling in None for shorter iterables. The reason for the difference is that infinite iterator arguments are typically an error for map() (because the output is fully evaluated) but represent a common and useful way of supplying arguments to imap().**

Comment: I see. They even reflected it in the docs!!! (I accept this answer in 10 min, when it will be allowed by SO).

Comment: Maybe you could try answering the other question which goes the last?

Comment: If you want the shortest of the two lists, then yes, using `imap` is completely reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

What about: `map(sum, zip([1,2,3],[4,5]))`?

Comment: I think this is better, because it doesn't require importing `imap`.